# Multithreaded server-client application sends multiple time the response

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap, server, client

I have a multithreaded server-client application. When I try to communicate between clients, the message I try to send is sent multiple times (e.g when I have 2-3 clients connected the message is sent 2 times, when I have 10 clients connected, the message is sent 6 times). Here is the code:

**The `ServerProtocol` Class**:

```
public class ServerProtocol {

    private String nick;
    private final ClientConn conn;

    private static final HashMap < String, ClientConn > nicks = new HashMap < > ();
    private static final String msg_WELCOME = "You are connected to server";
    private static final String msg_OK = "Message sent";
    private static final String msg_NICK_IN_USE = "Nick in use";

    private static final String msg_SEND_FAILED = "Failed to send";

    public ServerProtocol(ClientConn c) {
        nick = null;
        conn = c;
    }

    private byte[] authenticate(String mesaj) {

        String id = mesaj.substring(0, 1);

        if (!nicks.containsKey(id)) {
            nicks.put(id, this.conn);
            System.out.println(id + " joined.");
            this.nick = id;

            return msg_WELCOME.getBytes();

        } else {
            return msg_NICK_IN_USE.getBytes();
        }

    }

    public boolean sendMsgCSP(String recipient, String msg) throws IOException {
        if (nicks.containsKey(recipient)) {
            int e = nicks.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < e; i++) {
                ClientConn c = nicks.get(recipient);
                //c.sendMsgCC(nick.getBytes());
                c.sendMsgCC(msg.getBytes());
                System.out.println("message sent: " + msg + " to client " + recipient);
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public byte[] process(byte[] msg) throws IOException {
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(msg));
        String mesaj = new String(msg);
        if (!nicks.containsKey(nick)) {
            return authenticate(mesaj);
        }

        System.out.println("message:" + mesaj);

        if (sendMsgCSP(mesaj.substring(0, 1), mesaj.substring(1))) {
            return msg_OK.getBytes();
        } else {
            return msg_SEND_FAILED.getBytes();
        }
    }
}
```

**The `ClientConn`  Class:**

```
public class ClientConn implements Runnable {

    private final Socket clients;
    private OutputStream os;
    private DataOutputStream dos;
    private InputStream is;
    private DataInputStream dis;

    ClientConn(Socket client) {
        this.clients = client;

        try {
            is = clients.getInputStream();
            dis = new DataInputStream(is);
            os = clients.getOutputStream();
            dos = new DataOutputStream(os);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ClientConn.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        byte[] read, response;
        ServerProtocol protocol = new ServerProtocol(this);

        try {

            while (true) {
                read = readBytes();

                //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rd));
                //System.out.println("message received: " + Arrays.toString(read));
                response = protocol.process(read);

                sendMsgCC(response);


            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);

        }
    }

    public void sendMsgCC(byte[] myByteArray) throws IOException {
        int start = 0;
        int len = myByteArray.length;
        if (len < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative length not allowed");
        }
        if (start < 0 || start >= myByteArray.length) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Out of bounds: " + start);
        }

        dos.writeInt(len);
        if (len > 0) {
            dos.write(myByteArray, start, len);

        }
    }

    public byte[] readBytes() throws IOException {
        int len = dis.readInt();
        byte[] data = new byte[len];

        if (len > 0) {
            dis.readFully(data);
        }

        return data;

    }

}
```

I think the problem is on sendMsgCC method, but I can't figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < e; i++) {
        ClientConn c = nicks.get(recipient);
        c.sendMsgCC(msg.getBytes());
        System.out.println("message sent: " + msg + " to client " + recipient);
    }
```

You are sending message to recipient as many times as there are connected clients. Why the loop?

Also you have code reading and writing shared data from multiple threads without synchronization or locks, be prepared for problems.